# Possible to use ASPNET MVC2 without IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I know of the ServiceHost class, that lets me write a custom host for a WCF service. This means there's no requirement for IIS.  (I also know all the advantages of using IIS - no need to rehash those for me.).

Is there something similar to allow me to host ASPNET MVC2, without IIS?   Conversely, Is IIS a hard requirement for ASPNET MVC2?

Has anyone used [UltlDev Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/), and if so, what are your experiences?
Will it run ASPNET MVC2?

(I am using .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it on Cassini, Mono, IIS or host the whole asp.net runtime in your own application. (Actually pretty easy)

Comment: Yep - just to confirm - this worked on Ultidev.Cassini, which apparently is a derivation of Microsoft's Cassini. I was able to run an MVC2 app on that server, using .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Chris: do you have any pointers in hosting asp.net runtime in your own application or more specific, how would I go about seflhosting a MVC4 app (not Web API)?