# how to demonstrate a c# web application on other pcs?

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, web-deployment

I have developed c# .net web application and it is build on top of .NET Framework 4.0.

I have to show up my web application on my friend's PC without installing any software like Microsoft Visual Studio or IIS. In addition to the Visual Studio, i am also using MS SQL 2012 in my application.

Any suggestions how i can demonstrate my web app ?

Comment: Define "web application".

Comment: How do you plan to run a web application without a web server?

Comment: I don't need a web server right now, only one person will use it.

Comment: A web application needs to run on a web server (such as IIS, APACHE, etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378966/self-hosting-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Voting to close. This is a nonsensical question as it stands, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

**In short:** your web application needs to be **hosted** in some server (Web Server needs to be running and accessible to the PC that tries to make request to it), where your friend's PC has access.

Otherwise, you have to make a network between the PC'es.

If you never publish your web application to be hosted, here you are a good resource to look - [**How to upload my C# asp.net project to website(free hosting)**](http://forums.iis.net/t/1172179.aspx/1)

An informative ASP.NET Web project deployment tutorial may also help you - [**Deployment**](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment).

Comment: Just to add to this, the web server could be running on your friend's PC, it doesn't have to be a seperate computer

Comment: @Greg, you are right, however question says that no software/service  installation  is possible on friend's PC.

Answer (score 1):

Because you developed a web application..so

in order to make others to visit your website without anything installed.

you should publish your web application to a server(may be some free host,or virtual host.) which install everything ..

and then your friend can visit it just like you visit some normal website..