# self host mvc 6 application "dnx . web" command throw exception windows 8 machine

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

```
self host mvc 6 application *dnx . web* command throw exception in windows 8 machine  

i have followed the [link][1] to self host the mvc 6 application.

It has worked in visual studio 2015RC installed machine. but when we try to host other machine i got the below exception.
```

> C:\Users\Bigdata\Desktop\web4.5\src\web4._5>dnx . web
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Int32
>   System.Runtime.InteropSe rvices.Marshal.SizeOf(!!0)'. at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.SetRequestQueueLimit() at
>   Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()
>           at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump.Start(Func`2 app) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.ServerFactory.Start(IServerInformation
>   server, Func`2 app) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine.Start(HostingContext context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[]
>           args)

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298458/is-it-possible-to-self-host-a-mvc-6-application-without-iis-not-web-api
```

Answer (score 0):

`MissingMethodException` exception mostly means that you have mismatch between the runtime and package versions. Have a look at this blog pots to diagnose dependency issues:

[Diagnosing dependency issues with ASP.NET 5](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/)