# self-hosted ASP.NET core 2.2 full .NET framework on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to run an ASP.NET core 2.2 application on full .NET framework and IIS without having to install .NET core 2.2 on the server? It should be a self-contained application.

So it should run from IIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to self-host a ASP.NET Core Application without IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298458/is-it-possible-to-self-host-a-asp-net-core-application-without-iis)

Comment: Interpreted *literally* your question doesn't make much sense. You can't run a .NET Core application on the .NET Framework -- they're different frameworks. You can have a self-contained .NET Core application, but then that won't use the .NET Framework at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ASP.NET Core up to 2.2.x can run on both frameworks, and so can EF Core. It's like `Active Everything` in the 90s and `.NET Everything` in the 00s. ASP.NET Core 3 is the first version that only runs on .NET Core

Comment: Weird. I managed to miss that for some reason, and was under the impression ASP.NET Core effectively *was* .NET Core in the first version (and so not running on Framework, by definition). But apparently Framework support was always there from the first version. You can tell I don't do much ASP.NET development (Core or otherwise).

Comment: self-hosted and on IIS are mutually exclusive :P Self-hosted usually mean w/o hosting it in IIS (i.e. like self-hosted WCF services which directly act as an internet facing server. self-contained on other side means, application and per-app runtime are shipped together, similar to what some Java applications do who come with their own JRE and don't use the one installed on the system

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can both run ASP.NET Core 2.2 on full .net framework or dot net core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework