# Using SignalR Without an ASP.Net Core Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

After my research SignalR is a middleware I can use in ASP. Is it possible to host the server part in for example a console application or a dll?

I've read about SignalR webhost, but the guide is for .Net Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: SignalR is from 3.x is now native for .NET Core. What do you want to do exactly here? Using a .NET console app with SignalR Core?

Comment: SignalR has two components - server and client. Not sure if it is possible to have server without ASP(and from top of my head i don't see a lot of situations why you will need that) but client can be hosted [without ASP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @Kiril1512 Exactly, Like Hosting it in a console application, since I do not want an IIS.
Isn't SignalR just a middleware I can use in ASP ?
My question is only about the server part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking.

SignalR is built into ASP.NET core, you can reference and use it within the same application, which can be running in IIS, or self hosted, even asp.net core web apps are basically console apps, but there will need to be a web (internet aspect to your application.

There are also specific Azure services to handle signal R if that helps
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/signalr-service/

Comment: do you have a source for self hosted signalR in .net core?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298458/is-it-possible-to-self-host-a-asp-net-core-application-without-iis