# Can you host legacy ASP.NET MVC controllers using in-memory HttpServer in integration tests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I've seen a lot of examples around doing ASP.NET (.NET Framework not .NET Core) MVC integration tests using a `HttpServer` hosting an `ApiController`, but it doesn't seem to be able to host/expose a normal `Controller`.

For example, the following setup works:

**Controller**

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Debug()
    {
        return "This is debug content";
    }
}
```

**Test**

```cs
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}");
var server = new HttpServer(config);
var client = new HttpClient(server);
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://whatever/test/debug");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

If I change my `TestController` to extend `Controller` instead of `ApiController`, the response becomes 404.

Am I missing something here or this has never been supported?

Comment: Only ASP.NET Web API/SignalR can be self hosted (OWIN), but WinForms/MVC cannot. `ApiController` is exactly part of Web API, but not `Controller` for MVC.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, should post this as an answer.

Comment: That only remains a comment. If you want an answer on how to enable integration testing you might check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378966/self-hosting-asp-net-mvc