# Self host asp.net mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to self host and asp.net mvc site, just like with WCF services?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpListener` to implement a http server and inherit `MarshalByRefObject` to process asp.net request. Referring to this [Self-hosting ASP.NET MVC](http://www.ruurdkeizer.com/self-hosting-asp-net-mvc/)