# ASP.Net self-hosted application

Tags: asp.net-core, self-hosting

How to control ASP.Net 5 application from console application? All examples of self-hosted application I've found assume that the lifetime of the webserver matches the lifetime of application. Is it possible to have assembly of ASP.Net 5 application with `Startup.cs` file and main assembly (console app) which allows to start and stop web application using this `Startup` class when I need?
For example, Node.js allows to initiate new server at any place in code, like this

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) { /* processing request }).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

Is it possible to implement anything like this in ASP.Net 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the hosting API in your Program.Main, you can achieve the same thing.

UPDATE:
This is the RC1 API:

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs

post RC1 is very different

Comment: That link's dead, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can (re)create/(re)start the [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver(v=vs.118).aspx) when you like during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: As far as I understand this solution will work for previous versions of ASP.Net but not for the ASP.Net 5.