# How to self-host ASP.NET 5 MVC6 application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Just started learning ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6
I'm curious about self-hosting such an app outside of IIS - as a Windows service.
Should I be using TopShelf for that, like it was the case with OWIN/Katana apps, or does ASP.NET 5 provide some built-in self-hosting (as a service) options via a NuGet package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Kestrel](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#kestrel) library for self-hosting. 
Add dependency to the library in the `project.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    // Dependencies deleted for brevity.
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

Then scecify this command for Kestrel:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
}
```

You can start it by command line from the folder with your MVC project:

```
dnx web
```

Please, notify that `dnvm` must be runned before.

Comment: Will dnx run as a Windows background service?

Comment: No, it will run as a Windows process.

Comment: So, will this process terminate once the console window, from which it was launched is closed, or will it continue to run in the background?

Comment: You can specify new task in Windows Sheduler, for example. Then it will be runner in background mode. Or use third-party tools for running the process as a service.

Comment: This example uses owin and hosted in windows service - https://blog.uship.com/shippingcode/self-hosting-a-net-api-choosing-between-owin-with-asp-net-web-api-and-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0/

Answer (score 1):

All ASP.NET Core applications are self-hosted.

Yes you read it right!

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration() //// Here IIS integration is optional
            .UseStartup()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Have a look [here](https://neelbhatt40.wordpress.com/2016/10/09/mvc6-net-core-applications-are-self-hosted-optional-iis-integration/) for more details.